# Empty rows in csv file

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, csv

I need a little help, I exporting table to csv file, and this added me a 8 empty rows. Why ? Maybe anybody can help me a little bit.

export.ctp file

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $row):
    foreach ($row['Kontaktid'] as &$cell):
        // Escape double quotation marks
        $cell = '"' . preg_replace('/"/','""',$cell) . '"';
    endforeach;
    echo implode(',', $row['Kontaktid']) . "\n";
endforeach;
?>
```

And this is doing this

[image]

But I dont want these empty rows, when I import this file to mysql, then its added these empty rows too.

Thanks for helping !

If I type var dump, then I get this.
[image]

Comment: have you tried just `if ($row['Kontaktid']) continue;`?

Comment: <pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0)
<code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB"></span></span></code>
<span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB"></span><span style="color: #007700">if&nbsp
View::_evaluate() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 948
View::_render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 910
View::render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 471
Controller::render() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 954
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 198

Comment: Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 165
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 108</pre></div></pre>

Comment: `print_t($row)` and `print_r($row['Kontaktid'])` will be helpful information

Comment: can you to open your `csv` file in Notepad? not in Excel, how looks this empty lines in raw text?

Comment: this added 8 empty rows in notepad too .

Comment: stupid me, I meant `if (empty($row['Kontaktid'])) continue;`

Comment: This didnt change anything

Comment: Why you spend our time? Why can't you just `var_dump` your `$data` array, and we all must answer based on our assumptions?

Comment: @frantsium on the top of the file add `var_dump($data);` please!

Comment: I added a picture in to question

Comment: Read comment about linefeeds under my answer, I suggest your issue not related to provided code. Look for excess linefeeds after `?>`

Comment: @frantsium it's not the whole dump. And why you put it as a picture not text?

Comment: @frantsium your data seems fine and @vp_arth is maybe right about echoing some lines anywhere or something. It could be a CakePHP issues, but I cannot tell becasue I'm not familiar with CakePHP and `.ctp` files as a whole. Maybe you could dig there a little bit.

Comment: Yes, in controller I had excess linefeeds after `?>` and this made this problem, Thanks vp_arth . Maybe u put this in to answers or edit your answer, then I can accept it ;)

Comment: However, it is very strange, I do not echoing something like this in the code, there were just empty lines, and this gave these empty rows ?

Comment: @frantsium, ok, I update my answer. Just remove last `?>` to know, that you never repeat this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check, your line not empty:

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $row):
    if (!isset($row['Kontaktid']) || !$row['Kontaktid']) continue; // <-add this line
    foreach ($row['Kontaktid'] as &$cell):
        // Escape double quotation marks
        $cell = '"' . preg_replace('/"/','""',$cell) . '"';
    endforeach;
    echo implode(',', $row['Kontaktid']) . "\n";
endforeach;
```

May be issue is not in this code.
Check twice, that you have not any linefeeds echoing anywhere.
May be anything like:

```
   <?php
     //php code
    ?>
    ↓
    ↓
    ↓
```

All content outside your `<?php ?>` block is silent equivalent of `echo "...";`
So, these linefeeds are printed like `echo "\n\n\n\n";`

Good practice is to remove last `?>` at all

Comment: This didnt change anything

Comment: @frantsium `Kontactid` should be `Kontaktid` - you shouldn't make a clear copy paste...

Comment: May be issue is not in this code. Check twice, that you have not any linefeeds echoing anywhere. May be anything like `?>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$fh = fopen('./file1.csv', 'wt');
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (! empty($row['Kontaktid'])) {
        fputcsv($fh, $row['Kontaktid']);
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Replace `'./file1.csv'` with your filename and path. If you need to dump the CSV content on screen then replace the first line with `$fh = STDOUT;`

Comment: This give me a blank page and if I use `$fh = STDIN;` then I got error

Comment: try `fopen('php://stdin', 'wt');`

Comment: and it's a best solution, check not your page, but csv-file you writed.

Comment: If u use `fopen('php://stdin', 'wt');` then I get blank page

Comment: My mistake. It's `STDOUT`, not `STDIN`. Sorry.

Comment: I changed it in the answer.

Comment: Notice (8): Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' [APP\View\Kontaktid\export.ctp, line 2]

Warning (2): fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given [APP\View\Kontaktid\export.ctp, line 5]

Warning (2): fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given [APP\View\Kontaktid\export.ctp, line 5]Warning (2): fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given [APP\View\Kontaktid\export.ctp, line 8]

Comment: Hmm... in theory, `STDOUT` is the same as `fopen('php://stdout', 'wt')`. In reality, as your error shows us, it is not. It also happened to me, I didn't find the reason. Yet. Use `$fh = fopen('php://stdout', 'wt');` instead.

Comment: I already tried `$fh = fopen('php://stdout', 'wt');` This give me a blank page

Comment: Use `$fh = fopen('php://output', 'wt');`. It seems `STDOUT` and `'php://stdout'` are available [only when using the CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) but it's not easy at all to learn this from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using you code:

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $row):
    $isRowEmpty = false;
    foreach ($row['Kontaktid'] as &$cell):
        // we assume the row is empty if the first cell is empty
        if(empty($cell)) {
            $isRowEmpty = true;
            break;
        } else {
            // Escape double quotation marks
            $cell = '"' . preg_replace('/"/','""',$cell) . '"';
        }
    endforeach;
    if(!$isRowEmpty) {
        echo implode(',', $row['Kontaktid']) . "\n";
    }
endforeach;
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This didnt change anything

Comment: Could you make `print_r($row)` in foreach?

Comment: @vp_arth what do you mean?

Comment: @frantsium I'm still waiting for `print_r($row)`. We need cooperation in order to resolve your problem!

Comment: @divaka, I meant just typo, that I fixed. But your logic inverted also, if we have not iterations, we print empty line anyway.

Comment: @vp_arth that's why I need to check `$row`, because `Kontaktid` doesn't sound to me like an array, but more like a single cell. I want to check what is wrong with the $data and $row

Comment: @frantsium after `foreach ($data as $row):` put `print_r($row)` and give us the output.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: put a `;` at the end of `print_r($row);` It's very annoying because you don't even trying.

Comment: I try, sorry Im newby, and if I put a `;` at the end of `print_r($row)` then I got new error

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
if (isset($row['Kontaktid']) && strlen($row['Kontaktid']) && !empty($row['Kontaktid']))
```

before:

```
echo implode(',', $row['Kontaktid']) . "\n";
```

Comment: Warning (2): strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [APP\View\Kontaktid\export.ctp, line 7]

Warning (2): strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [APP\View\Kontaktid\export.ctp, line 7]